# Model not updating for embedded schema using DXA

Tags: dxa

I am working on DXA. 
My embedded schema is not filling in model "Career".
Please can you see what's wrong I am doing.
Details Below for your details.

In Schema following is being set as embedded schema. Details below:

In Design tab of Schema: Career

```
Schema "Career"    
XML Name: detail
    Description: Detail
    Type: Embedded Schema
    Embedded Schema: CareerDetail
```

Details below of Embedded Schema: CareerDetail

```
Name: CareerDetail
Description: Career Detail
Schema Type: Embeddable Schema
Root Element Name: CareerDetail
```

Model Details Below:

```
 [SemanticEntity(Vocab = SchemaOrgVocabulary, EntityName = "Career", Prefix = "s", Public = true)]
    public class Career : EntityModel
    {
        [SemanticProperty("s:detail")]
        public List<CareerDetail> CareerDetail { get; set; }
    }
```

Page Preview below to see the details for Career schema in Json

```
"career": {
    "Name": "career",
        "Values": [],
            "NumericValues": [],
                "DateTimeValues": [],
                    "LinkedComponentValues": [
                        {
                            "LastPublishedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                            "RevisionDate": "2019-05-18T19:26:31",
                            "Schema": {
                                "RootElementName": "Career",
                                "Id": "tcm:27-66723-8",
                                "Title": "Career"
                            },
                            "Fields": {
                                "country": {
                                    "Name": "country",
                                    "Values": [],
                                    "NumericValues": [],
                                    "DateTimeValues": [],
                                    "LinkedComponentValues": [],
                                    "FieldType": 3,
                                    "CategoryName": "test Career Countries",
                                    "CategoryId": "tcm:27-24802-512",
                                    "XPath": "tcm:Content/custom:Career/custom:country",
                                    "KeywordValues": [
                                        {
                                            "Description": "Australia",
                                            "Key": "australia",
                                            "TaxonomyId": "tcm:27-24802-512",
                                            "Path": "\\test Career Countries\\Australia",
                                            "ParentKeywords": [],
                                            "MetadataFields": {},
                                            "Id": "tcm:27-66520-1024",
                                            "Title": "Australia"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "detail": {
                                    "Name": "detail",
                                    "Values": [],
                                    "NumericValues": [],
                                    "DateTimeValues": [],
                                    "LinkedComponentValues": [],
                                    "EmbeddedValues": [
                                        {
                                            "division": {
                                                "Name": "division",
                                                "Values": ["Australia Division 1"],
                                                "NumericValues": [],
                                                "DateTimeValues": [],
                                                "LinkedComponentValues": [],
                                                "FieldType": 0,
                                                "XPath": "tcm:Content/custom:Career/custom:detail[1]/custom:division",
                                                "KeywordValues": []
                                            },
                                            "url": {
                                                "Name": "url",
                                                "Values": ["Australia URL 1"],
                                                "NumericValues": [],
                                                "DateTimeValues": [],
                                                "LinkedComponentValues": [],
                                                "FieldType": 0,
                                                "XPath": "tcm:Content/custom:Career/custom:detail[1]/custom:url",
                                                "KeywordValues": []
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "EmbeddedSchema": {
                                        "RootElementName": "CareerDetail",
                                        "Id": "tcm:27-66541-8",
                                        "Title": "CareerDetail"
                                    },
                                    "FieldType": 4,
                                    "XPath": "tcm:Content/custom:Career/custom:detail",
                                    "KeywordValues": []
                                }
                            },
                            "MetadataFields": {},
                            "ComponentType": 1,
                            "Categories": [],
                            "Version": 3,
                            "Id": "tcm:27-66726",
                            "Title": "Australia"
                        },
                        {
                            "LastPublishedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                            "RevisionDate": "2019-05-18T19:27:06",
                            "Schema": {
                                "RootElementName": "Career",
                                "Id": "tcm:27-66723-8",
                                "Title": "Career"
                            },
                            "Fields": {
                                "country": {
                                    "Name": "country",
                                    "Values": [],
                                    "NumericValues": [],
                                    "DateTimeValues": [],
                                    "LinkedComponentValues": [],
                                    "FieldType": 3,
                                    "CategoryName": "test Career Countries",
                                    "CategoryId": "tcm:27-24802-512",
                                    "XPath": "tcm:Content/custom:Career/custom:country",
                                    "KeywordValues": [
                                        {
                                            "Description": "UK",
                                            "Key": "uk",
                                            "TaxonomyId": "tcm:27-24802-512",
                                            "Path": "\\test Career Countries\\UK",
                                            "ParentKeywords": [],
                                            "MetadataFields": {},
                                            "Id": "tcm:27-66536-1024",
                                            "Title": "UK"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "detail": {
                                    "Name": "detail",
                                    "Values": [],
                                    "NumericValues": [],
                                    "DateTimeValues": [],
                                    "LinkedComponentValues": [],
                                    "EmbeddedValues": [
                                        {
                                            "division": {
                                                "Name": "division",
                                                "Values": ["UK Division 1"],
                                                "NumericValues": [],
                                                "DateTimeValues": [],
                                                "LinkedComponentValues": [],
                                                "FieldType": 0,
                                                "XPath": "tcm:Content/custom:Career/custom:detail[1]/custom:division",
                                                "KeywordValues": []
                                            },
                                            "url": {
                                                "Name": "url",
                                                "Values": ["UK URL 1"],
                                                "NumericValues": [],
                                                "DateTimeValues": [],
                                                "LinkedComponentValues": [],
                                                "FieldType": 0,
                                                "XPath": "tcm:Content/custom:Career/custom:detail[1]/custom:url",
                                                "KeywordValues": []
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "EmbeddedSchema": {
                                        "RootElementName": "CareerDetail",
                                        "Id": "tcm:27-66541-8",
                                        "Title": "CareerDetail"
                                    },
                                    "FieldType": 4,
                                    "XPath": "tcm:Content/custom:Career/custom:detail",
                                    "KeywordValues": []
                                }
                            },
                            "MetadataFields": {},
                            "ComponentType": 1,
                            "Categories": [],
                            "Version": 2,
                            "Id": "tcm:27-66727",
                            "Title": "UK"
                        }
                    ],
                        "FieldType": 6,
                            "XPath": "tcm:Content/custom:Feed/custom:career",
                                "KeywordValues": []
}
```

Comment: Seems to be very similar to https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/20065/component-link-data-is-null-in-dxa

Comment: In general, set the DXA log level to DEBUG to get more insight in how the semantic mapping works.

Comment: Many thanks.

I have problem accessing in dev environment. I need to do code change and send to implementer. So it is getting hard to investigate.
I am setting up my dev env but it will take some time. So need you assistance to fast track my request.

The problem lies with the camel case only. I made it to one word in previous example and it worked.
But my naming convention is not good for others if I say only details.

So, I made SemanticProperty as "s:detail" in the schema where I embedded the EmbeddedSchema "CareerDetail"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, this seems to be almost exactly the same problem as in [Component Link data is null in DXA](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/20065/component-link-data-is-null-in-dxa)

It is fine to have property names which don’t (exactly) match the CM field names, but you should use `SemanticProperty` annotations **in the Core Vocabulary** to map to CM fields.

Note that `SemanticProperty` annotations without a prefix are in the Core Vocabulary by default.

Also note that using the schema.org Vocabulary (as you are doing) only makes sense for semantic types/properties which are defined in http://schema.org (and “Carreer” is not).

Please check the DXA Documentation on semantic mapping: https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v11/GUID-2BED2168-26D2-465E-92D8-68C3D5219088

Unfortunately, there is a confusing mistake in that docs topic, though: the `Vocab` must be the `CoreVocabulary` (default), not the CM Schema namespace, unless you are using *Retrofit Mode*: https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v11/GUID-C0AD6DCC-ED65-441F-B361-928A18B2896D

Comment: That's fantastic. Many thanks. Last time I has issues with Camel case and using s at the trailing. Which was giving me the issue. I made everything with one word and all worked. This time I really wanted to make it work with correct name with no workarounds. This worked now.  Many thanks to you for your great help.